# Sed to remove all lines containing ROLE {rolename}

Tags: regex, sed

```
CREATE ROLE "postgres";
ALTER ROLE "postgres" WITH  INHERIT;
CREATE ROLE postgres;
ALTER ROLE postgres WITH  INHERIT;
CREATE ROLE "postgres-123";
ALTER ROLE "postgres-123" WITH  INHERIT;
```

Output should be :

```
CREATE ROLE "postgres-123";
ALTER ROLE "postgres-123" WITH  INHERIT;
```

Write a sed command to edit the file inplace to remove all occurrences of lines contains `ROLE postgres`(postgres can be with or without double quotes)

`sed -i -E "/ROLE postgres\\b/d" file_name` removes the `ROLE postgres` lines but does not removes lines where `postgres` is in double quotes.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Comment: 3-5 lines of sample data should be enough, right? Just include one of each case that should be deleted AND one record that should NOT be deleted. Your specification is ambiguous, *"lines contains ROLE postgres"* . "Contains" is different from "(exact) match" so you may want to check with your instructor about the scope of matching required. What are they trying to teach here, specification accuracy or unintended consequences of matching "short" versions of words versus longer versions (-;?! Good luck!

Comment: made required changes @shellter

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -r '/ROLE "? *postgres\b/d' filename
```

- `"?` = optional double quote
- `*` = any number of spaces, including 0
- `postgress\b` = `postgres` followed by a word boundary

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -E '/ROLE (postgres|"postgres")/d' file
CREATE ROLE "postgres-123";
ALTER ROLE "postgres-123" WITH  INHERIT;
```

Add `-i` or however else you want to update the input file when done testing.

If that doesn't do what you want then edit your question to includes cases where that doesn't work in your sample input/output.